# PayPal IPN not "VERIFIED" or "INVALID"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to integrate PayPal IPN on a website. For some reason the IPN listener is neither verifying the payment or marking it invalid. I have placed `mail()` functions at different points in the code to notify me how much of the program is being run.

I have tried with and without using `trim()` on the `$res` variable. Both ways fail.

Here is my code:

```
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    mail('test@test.net', 0, 0); //EMAIL RECEIVED
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
    $address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
    $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
    $address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
    $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
    $contact_phone = $_POST['contact_phone'];
    $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];


    if (!$fp) {
        //HTTP Error
        mail('test@test.net', 1, 1);
    } else {
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        mail('test@test.net', 2, 2); //EMAIL RECEIVED
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                mail('test@test.net', 3, 3);
            } else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0) {
                mail('test@test.net', 4, 4);
            } else {
                mail('test@test.net', 5, 5); //EMAIL RECEIVED
            }
        }
        fclose ($fp);
    }
}
```

The emails I am getting are 0, 2, and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just answered another like yours.  Paypal have stopped supporting HTTP1.0.  Your header should now read:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host:www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection:close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

If live, just change the host domain name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, It would be nice if PayPal would update their documentation when they make changes. I never would have figured that out.

Comment: I added a `mail()` function inside the `while (!feof($fp))` which emails me `trim($res)`. One of the emails it sends says "Invalid Host header".

Comment: Alright, it did end up verifying. It just came a little later than the other emails. Thanks

Comment: The `Host:` and `Connection:` headers there are missing their spaces.

Comment: @hg2000 I added the header to my code but $res is returning HTTP/1.1 200 OK and strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") is returning -1, how can I get the IPN Message?